# Add jQuery Confirm before Logout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I'm new to jQuery and I'm using the confirm box from [here](https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/#confirm). But I'm facing a problem where my current page redirects back to Login page before even confirming my logout in the dialog box.

Below is my script:

```
$('a#logout').on('click', function () {

                        var isConfirmed = $.confirm({
                            title: 'Logout Confirmation',
                            content: 'Are you sure you want to logout?',
                            buttons: {
                                confirm: function () {
                                    // $.alert('Confirmed!');
                                   return true;
                                },
                                cancel: function () {
                                    // $.alert('Canceled!');
                                    return false;
                                },
                            }
                        });

                        if(isConfirmed == true){
                            window.location.href="extra-login.html";
                        }

                    });
```

And this is my HTML

`<a href="extra-login.html" id="logout">
    Log Out <i class="entypo-logout right"></i>
</a>`

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: put redirect code in confirm callback and remove the href of anchor tag!

Comment: `href="extra-login.html"` to `href`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your anchor elements default action is to take the user to login page which is not prevented.

You can call the `event.preventDefault()` to do this.

Also the `confirm` plugin looks like a non blocking plugin, so you need to move the redirect code to the success handler.

```
$('a#logout').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var isConfirmed = $.confirm({
    title: 'Logout Confirmation',
    content: 'Are you sure you want to logout?',
    buttons: {
      confirm: function() {
        window.location.href = "extra-login.html";
      },
      cancel: function() {},
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the dialogue isn't blocking (I don't know of any that are in JS). You should just put your success code in the callback for the confirm button, like so:

```
$('a#logout').on('click', function () {

                        $.confirm({
                            title: 'Logout Confirmation',
                            content: 'Are you sure you want to logout?',
                            buttons: {
                                confirm: function () {
                                    // $.alert('Confirmed!');
                                    //I'm guessing this function is called when the button is clicked.
                                    window.location.href="extra-login.html";
                                   return true;
                                },
                                cancel: function () {
                                    // $.alert('Canceled!');
                                    return false;
                                },
                            }
                        });

                    });
```

But the main reason your code is redirecting immediately is the `href` tag in your link. You basically have a link to another page, that also tries to run some JS, but because it's a link it redirects before the JS can even run. Do this instead:

```
<a href="#" id="logout">
    Log Out <i class="entypo-logout right"></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

i am new,too
i hope my suggestion is right but why don't you put href in confirm function.

```
$('a#logout').on('click', function (event) {
     var isConfirmed = $.confirm({
                        title: 'Logout Confirmation',
                        content: 'Are you sure you want to logout?',
                        buttons: {
                            confirm: function () {
                               window.location.href="extra-login.html";
                            },
                            cancel: function () {
                              event.preventDefault();
                            },
                        }
                    });

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use like this -

```
$('a#logout').on('click', function(){
    if($(this).confirm({title: 'Logout Confirmation', content: 'Are you sure you want to logout?'})){
    window.location.href="extra-login.html";
}else{
    return false;
}
});
```